# Why does my backbone collection contain an empty model item?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a game model with a scorecards attribute that is a collection. I'm nesting this collection so when I initialize I'm using nestCollection to create the change handlers to keep everything updated and in sync. Whenever I create a new game model, an empty model is added to the scorecards attribute collection but only in memory - what is saved to localstorage is correct. I can't figure out why.

This is my game model definition- **Notice the console log statement results**:

```
var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({
localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('datastore'),
defaults: {
    name     : '',
    scorecards: new ScorecardList(),
    created   : 0
},

initialize : function() {
    console.log(this.scorecards);           // prints undefined
    console.log(this.get('scorecards'));    // length is 0 as expected

    this.scorecards = nestCollection(this, 'scorecards', new ScorecardList(this.get('scorecards')));

    console.log(this.scorecards);           // length is 1, with empty element in it
    console.log(this.get('scorecards'));    // length is 0 as expected

    if (this.isNew()) this.set('created', Date.now());
}
});
```

The nesting code:

```
function nestCollection(model, attributeName, nestedCollection) {
//setup nested references
for (var i = 0; i < nestedCollection.length; i++) {
    model.attributes[attributeName][i] = nestedCollection.at(i).attributes;
}
//create empty arrays if none

nestedCollection.bind('add', function (initiative) {
    if (!model.get(attributeName)) {
        model.attributes[attributeName] = [];
    }
    model.get(attributeName).push(initiative.attributes);
});

nestedCollection.bind('remove', function (initiative) {
    var updateObj = {};
    updateObj[attributeName] = _.without(model.get(attributeName), initiative.attributes);
    model.set(updateObj);
});
return nestedCollection;
}
```

This is the code I use to create a new game:

```
addGame: function () {
   var g = new Game({
       name:this.ui.gameName.val()
   });
   app.gameList.create(g,{wait:true});
   //Backbone.history.navigate('game/new/'+ g.id, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from this piece of code:

```
new ScorecardList(this.get('scorecards'))
```

Here you're giving your `ScorecardList` constructor another collection as argument. This collection happens to be an object. So your collection's constructor will think it's an object you're giving it to create a model.

So basically, `this.get('scorecards'))` gets cast into a `Scorecard` (or whatever your model is called), and that's why you have an empty model.

Passing arguments to the constructor for a different purpose than the creation of your collection is a bad idea, you should call a method afterwards.

Comment: Thanks - this is the trail I was following, but how would you recommend I pass the scorecards attribute to the collection for population?

Comment: I'm kind of troubled by what you want to do. Could you rephrase it? And by the way, putting a collection in the `defaults` object is generally a bad idea, as the same collection (instance, object) will be shared by all the instances of your `Game`.

Comment: You gave me the answer, or at least enough to figure it out myself. I needed to change the default scorecards setting from a collection to a standard array and move setting this default to the initializer if it did not exist already.